# Select one value from dropdown

Tags: javascript, protractor

I need to select one value from dropdown, I have written code like below

```
this.When(/^User should select equipment filter option$/,function(callback){

    var elem = mainpage.selectViewBy('#viewbyDropdown','Equipment');
            elem.click().then( function (){
            browser.sleep( 20000 );
            console.log("Equipment option is selected");
            callback();
      })
   });  

   selectViewBy: function(locator,Value) {
              var elm = browser.driver.findElement(by.css(locator));
              elm.click().then(function () {
               browser.sleep(2000).then(function () {
                var elem = element.all(by.css(locator + ' li')).filter(function (ele) {
                    return ele.getText().then(function (text) {
                        return text == Value;
                    });
                }).first();
            });
        });
```

But I am getting error like below

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
          at World.<anonymous>
```

Can someone help me on this issue

Comment: This looks like protractor code to me. Are you trying to test your application?

Comment: Yes Nata, it is protractor code only.Yes I am trying to test application

Comment: Could you please show us your html? Looks like something is wrong with your selection

Comment: Have you tried smth like this element(by.css(locator)).click().then(function () {
    ....
});

Answer (score 0):

I guess that in your selectViewBy, the elm is not locating the element.

```
var elm = browser.driver.findElement(by.css(locator));
```

Try with :

```
var elm = $(locator);
```

And verify that you really have the viewbyDropdown id in your dom at this moment.